# Как подключить зависимость к проекту?

Tags: c#, зависимости, xamarin-studio

Есть простейший проект на C# (command-line application). Я хочу подключить к нему сторонний проект в качестве модуля/зависимости. Я не буду менять код подключаемого проекта, но хочу использовать его классы. Проект доступен в виде [репозитория на GitHub](https://github.com/gsscoder/commandline).

Работаю на Xamarin Studio, Mono, OS X. Если это будет совершенно необходимо, могу перейти на Visual Studio на Windows.

Пока что вижу следующие пути решения:

1. Найти аналог Maven для C#. (На Java я бы шел именно этим путем). Пока что поиск не дал никакого лидирующего решения. Предлагаются разные варианты, но они то непопулярны, то вовсе поддержка прекращена.
2. Подключать submodule в Git и сам проект как-то импортировать в Xamarin Studio.

Как вообще принято подключать зависимости в .net?

UPD: Похоже, что решение называется NuGet. В качестве ответа хотелось бы пошаговую инструкцию по подключению зависимости.

Comment: Если с MSVS и nuget, то там буквально [делать нечего](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/Package-Manager-Dialog). Всё работает из коробки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Xamarin Studio есть интеграция с NuGet, начиная с 3-й версии Xamarin.

- Открываете окно Solution
- Right Click по проекту, выбираете Add / Add Packages. 
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- В диалоге ищете нужный вам пакет, нажимаете Add. 
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
  В официальном блоге есть [пошаговая инструкция с картинками](https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-studio-and-nuget/).